# Последовательный вызов одной и той же функции (напоминает перехват)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующее: в коде некоторой программы есть функция:

```
void main() {
    print("Вызов №1");
}
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы следом произошел вызов такой же функции main, содержащий представленный ниже код, из другого файла?

```
void main() {
    printf("Вызов №2");
}
```

И как результат я в консоле увидел две строки:

```
Вызов №1
Вызов №2
```

Это чем-то напоминает мне перехват функции. Но, к сожалению, не совсем понимаю, как его правильно реализовать. Делаю это для модульного проекта, чтобы каждый файл содержал в себе код отдельной системы.

Comment: [execv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv)

Comment: Они у вас в разных исполнимых файлах или вы хотите размещать их в одном выполнимом файле, но в разных исходниках?

Comment: вопрос бессмысленный, что сейчас мешает поместить эти две функции (в отдельных пространствах имен естественно) в двух разных файлах а затем вызывать их?

Comment: Дело в том, что хотелось бы получить проект, в котором можно было бы отключать и добавлять файлы без внесения каких-либо поправок в код. Таким образом должен получиться проект, в котором каждый файл независим друг от друга и [каждый файл] содержит реализацию основной функции main.